# StackOverlowError when building project with maven

Tags: java, lombok

I am running the commands `clean, install` to build the project. `clean` executes just fine, but it errors out when it reaches the `install` phase, saying that lombok is causing a StackOverflowError, without really providing any classes or line numbers, which makes it very hard for me to debug. I checked online and it's saying that often times this is caused by lombok doing circular calls, but I wouldn't really know where that could be the case. The only solution thing I can think of is to delombok the project, but since the codebase is fairly large I'd prefer to avoid it

```
Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1145)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:173)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile (Main.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at lombok.core.AST.fieldsOf (AST.java:226)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:357)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:323)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:183)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree (JavacAST.java:66)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0 (AST.java:386)
    at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField (AST.java:284)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:357)
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression (JavacAST.java:323) (it continues with this last error several hundred times)
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the stack size?

Comment: I just added <meminitial>1024m</meminitial><maxmem>2024m</maxmem> inside pom.xml as configuration for the compiler plugin, but that didn't help.

Comment: That doesn't change the stack size. If you are using fork = false you'll need to set it on the maven command itself, if fork is true, use https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs

Comment: This usually happens because you have circular dependency between two classes and the tostring or hashcode just keeps recursing. So, look for classes that include each other.

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you, I'll try that. I've tried looking for ToString and EqualsHashCode usages, but have found none. Is there anything else you can think of that I could try?

Comment: Of course as @rmfeldt suggests it may be a real cycle, in which case increasing the stack size won't help (does Lombok really not detect cycles?)

Comment: Yes that's what surprised me as well, but I saw it in other answers as well. Having said that, as I mentioned, ToString and EqualsHashCode annotations aren't used in the project.

Comment: TBH I haven't used Lombok in a long time as I am currently doing c++ projects. So it might have been fixed. A quick search showed up a bug on their github regarding long chained method calls. https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1118. But in that case increasing stack size appears to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but sadly increasing the stack size didn't help, it still has the same issue. Is there anything else I can try? My idea right now is basically to delombok the whole project and gradually reintroducing its annotations making sure they work, but that doesn't seem like a great solution. Can anyone think of anything else?

Comment: Run under the debugger, and find somewhere in Lombok where you can put a breakpoint which logs the class Lombok is working on. Hopefully the last one you see logged will be involved with the problem.

Comment: And are you certain that you did increase the stack size -- do you have fork true, or false?

Comment: I added -Xss1000m to the Runner, though without configuring the fork tag, not entirely sure why. Everything seems to be working fine now, thanks a lot for the help and suggestions.